# Unable to export test result in Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, xcode, sonarqube, fastlane, xcode11.4

I am using following code to export test code coverage using Xcode11.4.

```
./xccov-to-sonarqube-generic.sh /DerivedData/MyApp-*/Logs/Test/*.xcresult/ > sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml
```

I am getting following error

> This version of Xcode does not support opening result bundles created
>   with versions of Xcode and xcodebuild using the v1 API

Kindly help me with the proper way.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any luck?

Comment: Found a way of doing it using XCParse, Haven't tried it yet, which converts XCResult to Xcode 10 xccovarchive. For now I have added try catch in my Analysis step to pass through

Comment: Got it working without wildcards in the path (*). No idea why tough.

Answer (score 3):

3 work arounds here for this as for as my research:

1. There is an update to xccov-to-sonarqube-generic.sh script for Xcode 11+. Try using this

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/blob/master/swift-coverage/swift-coverage-example/xccov-to-sonarqube-generic.sh

2. Use Code Coverage Converter (cococo) utility to generate sonar's xml file format. Refer for more info:

https://medium.com/monsterculture/cococo-code-coverage-converter-from-xcode-11-to-sonarqube-7f48cff97b9b

3. Any shell script that is capable to convert Xocde 11+ *.xcresult file to sonar's xml file format